# Empty Localizable.strings after importing .xliff file using Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, localization, xliff

I'm testing the export/import localizations flow as suggested in Apple's [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1) by doing the following:

1. Create a new iOS project using the Single View Application template
2. Set the ViewController's title like this 
   `override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       title = NSLocalizedString("Hello", comment: "Salutation")
   }`
3. Add a new localization to the project (I chose Italian)
4. Export the .xliff file for the Italian localization by using the **Editor** > **Export For Localization...** command
5. Edit the it.xliff file and translate `"Hello"` to `"Ciao"`
6. Import the it.xliff file by using the **Editor** > **Import Localizations...** command
7. Xcode adds both Localizable.strings and InfoPlist.strings files to the project (in the it.lproj folder)
8. Open the Localizable.strings and/or InfoPlist.strings file and notice the only thing in there is `/* No Localized Strings */`

I could go with the *old fashioned* `genstrings` approach, but if someone could point me in the right direction with using xliff files I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post: https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

You have to add all the hard coded keys in your classes to Localizable.strings (English)

So what you have to do is:

Change

```
title = NSLocalizedString("Hello", comment: "Salutation")
```

To

```
title = NSLocalizedString("general.greeting", comment: "Salutation")
```

Then, add this to your Localizable.strings (English):

```
"general.greeting" = "Hello";
```

Then, export for localization, something like this will be written in the .xliff file:

```
<trans-unit id="general.greeting">
  <source>Hello</source>
  <note>Salutation</note>
</trans-unit>
```

Add your Italian localized version for the greeting using `<target></target>`:

```
<trans-unit id="general.greeting">
  <source>Hello</source>
  <target>Ciao</target>
  <note>Salutation</note>
</trans-unit>
```

Import for localization and the Localizable.strings (Italian) should contain the localization.

Comment: Now I see the problem with my workflow: the Localizable.strings files need to exist for all localizations **before** using the **Editor > Export For Localization...** (my understanding was that they were created upon import of the .xliff files).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately XCode doesn't create it automatically